# jQuery .css does not add display:block; for all divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi jQuery script does not add display block for all same mane divs, only for the first one.

JS

```
$("#sidecontrol_container").mouseenter(function(){
    setTimeout( function(){
    $('#packet_name').css('display','block');
       },310);
$( "#sidecontrol_container" ).animate({
        width:"230px"
    }, 300 );       
});
$("#sidecontrol_container").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#packet_name').css('display','none');
    $( "#sidecontrol_container" ).animate({
        width:"40px"
    }, 300 );   
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="sc_wraper">
    <div id="packet_name">1</div>
</div>

<div id="sc_wraper">
    <div id="packet_name">1</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#packet_name{
    height:40px;
    width:190px;
    float:right;
    display:none;
}
```

It only adds for first div with name packet_name `<div id="packet_name" style="display:block;">1</div>`

HTML RESULT after mouseenter

```
<div id="sc_wraper">
        <div id="packet_name" style="display:block;">1</div>
    </div>

    <div id="sc_wraper">
        <div id="packet_name">1</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to use div classes instead, IDs are only for single occurrences on a page. Then adjust your jQuery as appropriate

Comment: @robobobobo why don't you add that as an answer? Your suggestion seemed to have worked for Vadimas.

Comment: Sure thing jsve, added it now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is only changing the first one is because jQuery only selects the first instance of the div name since its an ID.

If you want to change multiple divs of the same name you need to use div classes instead for their names. Once you update your html to use class names, do the same with jQuery and it should work

Comment: OMG. such a silly mistake but I wouldn't have thought of it (I'm relatively new to these languages.) Thank you!!